# How to compare a array with another array stdclassobject and access it key in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php with codeigniter. When I did the `print_r`, I got the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [UserName] => fun
        [UserCode] => 6
        [GroupCode] => 1
        [GroupName] => Master
        [MenuCode] => 0
        [MenuName] => 
        [Admin] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [UserName] => fun
        [UserCode] => 6
        [GroupCode] => 1
        [GroupName] => Master
        [MenuCode] => 1
        [MenuName] => Item Master
        [Admin] => 0
    )

)
```

In another hands I have another set of array,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Billing Report
  [1] => Waiterwise Report
  [2] => Admin
  [3] => User Master
  [4] => User Rights
  [5] => Close Session
  [6] => Close Day
)
```

Now i want to compare Group name in the above two array and want the key as result.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare Group name"? How do you want to compare them? And how does this have anything to do with CodeIgniter? It looks to be just a simple PHP question.

Comment: I want to compare them.  For example. In the second, Admin is a group a name. So i want to verify that the second array items are related to group name or menu name.

Comment: which array key you want as result ?

Comment: First array key i need as a result...

Comment: I'm new to PHP. So I don't know how to do this Olsen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result_array = array();
foreach($codeigniter_array as $k=>$r)
{
    foreach($r as $k1=>$r1)
    {
        if(in_array($r1, $group_array))
        {
            $result_array[$k1] =$r1;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result_array);die;
```

Comment: Its working, But i need '[GroupName] => Admin'...And i need this key so the expected result is "GroupName".

Comment: Hi Brijal , Can u got my question? I want the key inside stdclass object

Comment: if two keys are compared as result then what will be your result array ? @SaranPHP I have also updated my code please check

Comment: Hi Brijal, I have array like {reports, day report, night report}..In this three values.. Reports only belongs to group name, others belongs to Menuname, But your code just reflect for the last item night report and not for the remaining item.

Comment: i have update code, please check if still something missing then please let me know ?

Comment: Thanks for your great support Brijal

Comment: working for you @SaranPHP ? if yes then feel free to accept and UV this answer :)